# Validating a Rails model post-save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model with a couple of accepts_nested_attributes_for.  There is a requirement that I have at least one of each of the nested attributes when saving and moving on.

However, validation occurs pre-save, so when I'm removing an item and moving on, it let's it through.

How can I validate that when I've saved, I have at least one item of each nested type there?

Comment: What would you did if it failed validation?

Comment: @Neil: No, I mean that the invalid model is now saved, so you will need to adjust the model.

Comment: I bit more info would probably help. Maybe you could post the code you are using to check if there is at least one of each type :)

Comment: Are you looking to prevent object from destruction with validations. Or create if a new record along an association if there aren't any after an update?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a bug with [accepts_nested_attributes_for](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/2646-validations-not-called-when-model-updating-using-nested-attributes). Meaning you have to be a little more devious when it comes to validations in the parent model.

You could use an :after_save callback in each of your nested models to check if it's the last one. But if there's many nested associations where you want to ensure at least one, this isn't very DRY.

This is however a valid workaround for the linked bug:

```
class Whatever < ActiveRecord::Base
  :has_many => :association_a
  :has_many => :association_b

  def ensure_minimum_associations
    bad_associations =  [:association_a, :association_b].
      select{|assoc| self.send(assoc).all?{|a| a.marked_for_destruction?}}
    unless bad_associations.empty?
      bad_associations.each do |association|
        errors.add_to_base "Each #{self.class.name.downcase} must retain at least one #{association}"
      end
      return false
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always call `valid?` on a model and it will run the validation.

Comment: I realise that, but I need it to happen before save - the parent object get's saved before the nested attributes

Comment: If any validation returns false the entire transaction is rolled back. Regardless of whether it's in the parent or nested models.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for [validates_associated](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_associated)